# Simple or complex sentences?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I have a problem with identifying whether this type of sentences is simple or complex:

> **Besides** stealing jewels, he also murdered her.
>   **In spite of** my advice, she gave up her studies.

The prepositions "besides" and "in spite of" confuse me.

Could you please help me to identify this type of sentences?

Answer (score 1):

"In spite of" is a preposition group. It is followed only by a noun, not by a clause. "besides"is a simple preposition. As you have no subclause in your two examples you have simple sentences.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples

> he also murdered her
>   she gave up her studies

are both the simple sentence (independent clause) portions of your complex sentences